# finishAffinity doesn't kill async tasks

Tags: java, android

When I am calling `finishAffinity`, I observe that it does not kill the Async Tasks which were opened from other activities.

How can I finish all Async Tasks from other Activities when I am calling `finishAffinity`?

```
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: if you read the documentation of finishAffinity, this api is used for Finish current activity as well as all activities immediately below it in the current task that have the same affinity. Does user flow comes under this?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION 1**

If you are finishing from another activity, you can try overriding onDestroy() method on the activity which is executing your AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(asyncTask != null) {
        asyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

---

**SOLUTION 2**

Alternatively, you can start your next activity with `startActivityForResult()` and you can `setResult()` when you called `finishAffinity()`. On the previous activity, you need to check the result by overriding `onActivityResult()` method. Check if your result is set when the `finishAffinity()` called, you can call the cancel method like this:

```
if(asyncTask != null) {
    asyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```

[How to Get Result from an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

---

**SOLUTION 3**

Also you can use **Observer** pattern and **Event Bus** to trigger an event from next activity and catch it from previous activity. When the event triggered, you can detect it and cancel your **asyncTask**.

[EventBus library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the `AsyncTask` from the `onDestroy` function of your `Activity`. When the `Activity` is getting finished, it should stop the `AsyncTask` created earlier using their reference.

Let us assume `ActivityA` has started the following `AsyncTask`.

```
// You might have started your AsyncTask like this
private YourAsyncTask mTask;
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

In your `onDestroy` function of the `ActivityA` write the following.

```
if(mTask != null) mTask.cancel(true);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont want exactly to destroy it on my next activity. I want to destroy it on my next's activty  button event click

Comment: You might consider having a `public static` variable which might help in this case. I am not sure about your exact use case. However, I am just putting some ideas. I am not sure if they are applicable in your case.